# Bootstrap/Foundation stacking rows/columns

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, zurb-foundation, rows

I'm trying to achieve very simple two row stacking but can't seem to find the solution. I've tried Bootstrap and Foundation for solutions. 
As you can see in the photos I have 2 rows, each with 3 columns. When the screen size is medium/small i need the columns to be in 2 parts, Heading 4 should be next to Heading 3 and Heading5 underneath Heading3. Heading6 follows afterwords.

I thank everyone greatly in advance!

[how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqFGy.png)

[what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W58Yz.png)

Bootstrap code

```html
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading3</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading4</h2>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading6</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Foundation code

```html
 <div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="primary callout">
      <p>Four columns</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="primary callout">
      <p>Four columns</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-6 end columns">
    <div class="primary callout">
      <p>Four columns</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-4 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="primary callout">
      <p>Four columns</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="primary callout">
      <p>Four columns</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 medium-6 columns">
    <div class="primary callout">
      <p>Four columns</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to do by Bootstrap.

We need only one row with six cells. It's because Bootstrap [wraps the extra cells onto new lines](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

The block with the class `col-xs-6` takes 6 from 12 columns. It is exactly half of the screen width. This class works, until [a condition for a wider screen](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) starts to act. The block with the class `col-sm-4` occupies a third of the width of the screen, when the screen is `992px` or wider.

Please check the result.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading4</h2> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading6</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use two different row. Bootstrap default wraps the extra cells/columns in next row.
[Read documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-default"> more info.</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-default"> more info.</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-default"> more info.</button>
    </div>



    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading4</h2> 
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
      </p>
  <button class="btn btn-default"> more info.</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading5</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-default"> more info.</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <h2>Heading6</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor 
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-default"> more info.</button>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```